# mouseleave event is triggered when I choose an option of select although it's not outside of the area

Tags: jquery, html, css, mouseevent, mouseleave

I have  which hosts an image inside of it. When one hovers, another  is laid over it with a few options, among them a . When the mouse leaves this , then the overlaid  disappears.

More specifically:

HTML

```
 <li id="pos-1" class="hoverable">
    <img src="/3676136a.jpg?1445498347" width="170"  border="0" >
    <div class="hover-window">
      <div class="view-holder"> 
       <select autocomplete="off" >
         <option disabled="" selected="selected" value="-1">Pick a view...  </option>    
         <option value="1">BOOT</option>    
         <option value="2">COCKPIT</option>   
         <option value="3">FRONT</option>   
       </select>
      </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

jquery

```
  var onPhoto = $(this).find(".hover-window");
  $('.hoverable').on('mouseenter',function(e) {
    console.log("entered the area");
    e.stopPropagation();
    onPhoto.fadeIn();
  });

  $('.hoverable').on('mouseleave',function(e) {
    console.log("left the area");
    e.stopPropagation();
    onPhoto.fadeOut();
  });
```

Of course, this works on Chrome, but Chrome is generally very "smart" and has many helpful functions which help him understand what one wants to do. However, sometimes they may mislead you when it comes to cross-browsing.
On firefox and IE, the moment that select > option is hovered, then the .hover-window disappears.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Am i getting it right that you want the hover effect only to appear on the picture and not on the rest of the code?

Comment: Yes exactly. Imagine a photo, which gets a darker overlay that displays options. That darker overlay is triggered with hover-window class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of jquery events and because legacy browser compatibility is required, I solved it by removing all the relative jquery events and inserting CSS z-index rules instead:

```
.hoverable{
  display:inline-block;
  margin: 3px;
  z-index: 3;
  position: relative;
} 
.hover-window
{
 display:none;
 position:relative;
 top: -127px;
 width:170px;
 height:127px;
 color:#fff;
 background: RGBA(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
 z-index: 1;
 -webkit-transition: background 0.2s ease-in;
 -moz-transition: background 0.2s ease-in;
 -ms-transition: background 0.2s ease-in;
 -o-transition: background 0.2s ease-in;
 transition: background 0.2s ease-in;
}
 .hoverable:hover .hover-window
{
 display:block;
 z-index:10;
}
```

I'll do some extra rules for IE8 because rgba is not working there.

**Thanks a lot for your insight guys**. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

So, in relation to your comment i made a fiddle which is working with adding and removing css class. the picture now get's a darker overlay with options on it. I hope that is what you are looking for.

```
 var onPhoto = $(this).find(".hover-window");
  $('.hoverimage').on('mouseenter',function(e) {
    console.log("entered the area");
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(".hoverable").css("display", "block");
  });

  $('.hoverable').on('mouseleave',function(e) {
    console.log("left the area");
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(".hoverable").css("display", "none");
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5uvayph8/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `fadeOut` is causing the element to be hidden.

I would use `.css()` to change its opacity instead:

```
var onPhoto = $(this).find(".hover-window");
  $('.hoverable').on('mouseenter',function(e) {
    console.log("entered the area");
    e.stopPropagation();
    onPhoto.css('opacity', '1');
  }).on('mouseleave',function(e) {
    console.log("left the area");
    e.stopPropagation();
    onPhoto.css('opacity', '0');
  });
```

[**Example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/p94Lw1xx/4/)

With a little bit of css, you can retain the fade effect:

```
.hover-window{
    transition: all .5s;
}
```